# Wp_list_table search box not working for custom value from database

Tags: plugin-development, wp-list-table

I am creating a from builder , so in wp list table i am unable to achieve search result from database for from builder entries, Please get attached link for example.

Search submission : https://prnt.sc/ro6mr1
Getting search value : https://prnt.sc/ro6nw1
Search Process : https://prnt.sc/ro6npf
Output :https://prnt.sc/ro6ooh

Please give me a solution ,
NB :This list table is made for getting from entries.

Thanks